# perl query using -pie

Tags: perl

This works:

```
perl -pi -e 's/abc/cba/g' hellofile
```

But this does not:

```
perl -pie 's/cba/abc/g' hellofile
```

In other words -pi -e works but -pie does not. Why?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `-i` flag takes an optional argument (which, if present, must be immediately after it, not in a separate command-line argument) that specifies the suffix to append to the name of the input file for the purposes of creating a backup.  Writing `perl -pie 's/cba/abc/g' hellofile` causes the `e` to be taken as this suffix, and as the `e` isn't interpreted as the normal `-e` option, Perl tries to run the script located in `s/cba/abc/g`, which probably doesn't exist.

Answer (score 10):

Because `-i` takes an optional extension for backup files, e.g. `-i.bak`, and therefore additional flags cannot follow directly after `-i`.

From [perldoc perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html)

> -i[extension]
>
> specifies that files processed by the <> construct are to be edited
>   in-place. It does this by renaming the input file, opening the output
>   file by the original name, and selecting that output file as the
>   default for print() statements. The extension, if supplied, is used to
>   modify the name of the old file to make a backup copy, following these
>   rules:
>
> If no extension is supplied, no backup is made and the current file is
>   overwritten.
>
> If the extension doesn't contain a * , then it is appended to the end
>   of the current filename as a suffix. If the extension does contain one
>   or more * characters, then each * is replaced with the current
>   filename. In Perl terms, you could think of this as:

Answer (score 8):

perl already tells you why :) **T**ry-**I**t-**T**o-**S**ee

```
$ perl -pie " s/abc/cba/g " NUL
Can't open perl script " s/abc/cba/g ": No such file or directory
```

If you use B::Deparse you can see how perl compiles your code

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -pi -e " s/abc/cba/g " NUL
BEGIN { $^I = ""; }
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    s/abc/cba/g;
}
continue {
    die "-p destination: $!\n" unless print $_;
}
-e syntax OK
```

If you lookup $^I in perlvar you can learn about the -i switch :)

```
$ perldoc -v "$^I"

    $INPLACE_EDIT
    $^I     The current value of the inplace-edit extension. Use "undef" to
            disable inplace editing.

            Mnemonic: value of -i switch.
```

Now if we revisit the first part, add an extra -e, then add Deparse, the -i switch is explained

```
$ perl -pie -e " s/abc/cba/g " NUL
Can't do inplace edit: NUL is not a regular file.

$ perl -MO=Deparse -pie -e " s/abc/cba/g " NUL
BEGIN { $^I = "e"; }
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    s/abc/cba/g;
}
continue {
    die "-p destination: $!\n" unless print $_;
}
-e syntax OK
```

Could it really be that e in -pie is taken as extension? I guess so

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -pilogicus -e " s/abc/cba/g " NUL
BEGIN { $^I = "logicus"; }
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    s/abc/cba/g;
}
continue {
    die "-p destination: $!\n" unless print $_;
}
-e syntax OK
```

When in doubt, Deparse or Deparse,-p