# perl -pi.bak -e "tr/\n\r/ /d" test.XML

Tags: perl

I never learned Perl and try to understand a piece written by someone else. Could someone tell me what `perl -pi.bak -e "tr/\n\r/ /d" test.XML` means? Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not take a look at [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html)?

Comment: @Alec it's easy **if you know** where to look for a specific information, but difficult if you don't...

Answer (score 9):

```
perl -pi.bak -e "tr/\n\r/ /d" test.XML
```

- `-p` read input from argument file or standard input (implicit while loop around program)
- `-i.bak` perform in-place edit on argument file and save a copy with extension `.bak`.
- `-e` the code
- `tr/\n\r/ /d` transliterate all characters in the left hand side `\n\r` to their corresponding character in the right hand side  (a space), and `/d` delete any entries which do not have a corresponding character.

So basically this will take the file `test.XML`, store a copy in `test.XML.bak`, change all newlines to space, delete all line feed characters `\r`, and save this copy as `test.XML`.

Be aware that you can overwrite backups by running this command multiple times. The backup is not backed up.

Comment: This detailed explanation made me think about and [understand](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7935829/2932052) why the `-pi` and `-e` parts are separated. I mean, the `-i` switch is indeed somewhat surprising.

Answer (score 2):

Briefly, it's executing the script following `-e` for each line of the input file `test.XML`. It then writes the modifications back to the input file and retains the original file with a `.bak` suffix. I would create a sample XML file and try it out. You'll see that your original file is modified (check the filesystem dates) and the original retained with the `.bak` suffix.

The `tr` function is documented [here](http://www.misc-perl-info.com/perl-tr.html), and translates characters. The above is manipulating carriage-returns/line-feeds.

The `-p` and `-i` arguments let Perl rename the input file such that it's retained as a backup of the original. See [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) for more details.

See [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/ksplice/entry/the_top_10_tricks_of) for more tips/tricks relating to Perl one-liners.

Comment: `tr/\n\r/ /d` does not convert line feeds to spaces, it deletes them.

Answer (score 1):

It changes the newlines in test.XML to be spaces. It will also backup the original file as test.XML.bak.