# how to delete the line after a regex match in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I would like to delete the line after a regex match but I'm unsure how to code for deleting the next line in Perl - help?

```
while ( my $line = <FILE> ) {
if ($line =~ m/(regex)/i) {
# delete the next $line
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What do you mean "delete"?  You mean ignore it?

```
while ( my $line = <FILE> ) {
    if ( $line =~ /regex/ ) {  # If it matches this regex
        my $ignored = <FILE>;  # read the next line and ignore it.
    }
}
```

Comment: I would like to delete the line after a regex match from the file or alternatively print a new file without the lines after the regex match

Comment: @neemie that's just exactly what doing nothing with `$ignored` would do. You would read in another line and ignore it. When you get back up to the top of the loop, you will read the line 2 lines after the match.

Answer (score 0):

What about having a `$skip_flag` that you set when you come across a match? As you're reading your file line by line, you could build an output string, skipping lines when the flag is set.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( $line =~ /regex/ ) {  # If it matches this regex
    <FILE>;  # gobble gobble
}
```

Is all you need my friend.

Answer (score 0):

You can run `$> perl -pi -e 'BEGIN{undef $/;} s#(YOUR_REGEX_PATTERN)[^\n]*\n[^\n]*\n#$1\n#' YOUR_FILE`

This is able to do a [multiline replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030787/multiline-search-replace-with-perl/1030819#1030819) by forcing Perl to [read the entire file at once](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Variables-related-to-filehandles).
But be **always** sure to make a backup first! You may let Perl do it for you by [appending a suffix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935829/perl-query-using-pie/7935854#7935854) to that `-i` switch like `$> perl -pi.bak -e ...`